# Using the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help please with the following question. (Do I need to use radians in dealing   with the $\sin$ part?))

(a) Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that the equation $x + \sin(x) = 1$, has at 
     least one solution in the interval $[0,1]$.

(b) Find an approximation of the solution with an error of at most $0.05$.

Comment: (a) Take $f(x)=x+\sin x - 1$.  Now what are $f(0)$ and $f(1)$?

Comment: (b) Can you find an interval $[a, b]$ of length $b - a \leq 0.1$ so that $f(a)\leq 0 \leq f(b)$? How far away from a solution can the midpoint $(a + b)/2$ be? And yes, I would assume the $\sin$ part is in radians unless degrees are specifically stated.

Answer (score 0):

(a)Take $\,f(x)=x+\sin x−1$ .Now you can see that $f(0)$ is negative and $f(1)$ is positive, So $f(x)$ will be zero for some intermediate value. So, equation will have a solution.
(b)find $f(0.5)$ and see if it is positive then solution will lie between $0$ and $0.5\,$ else it will lie between $0.5$ and $1$, then go to appropriate range and keep doing it further .

Comment: I have attempted part (b) as follows:
Part (b):
f(0) =-1, f(0.1) = -0.9, f(0.2) = -0.8, f(0.3) = -0.7, f(0.4) = -6, f(0.5) = -0.5, f(0.6) = -0.4, f(0.7) = -0.3, f(0.8) = -0.2, f(0.9) =-0.08, f(1) = +0.02
Therefore the root lies in the interval [0.9, 1]
Therefore the midpoint (0.95) approximates the root with an error of at most 0.05
Your comments would be welcomed.